# Seaborn histplot with a condition

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Hi I am trying to draw a graph using seaborn, but I only want to use those subject_id, which have a value of 23.

```
g = sns.histplot(data=dfsolutions, x= 'subject_id' ,y='time_left' ,color='green')
plt.show()
```

This is what I have so far, but I am unable to find how to add any condition. I tried using .query but it does not work or I tried it incorrectly.

Comment: How the data looks like? Can you add a simple example of that data-frame?

Comment: It is just a basic table with some attributes, columns are id, subject_id, start, stop, time_left and rows are intigers with according numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without sample data or a minimal running example I cannot say exactly what you need, but my sensible guess is that what you need is to select that subset and feed it to seaborn. Also, I guess what you want is to make the hist of `time_left` values of subject 23.

```py
g = sns.histplot(data=dfsolutions[dfsolutions["subject_id"]==23], x= 'time_left', color='green')
plt.show()
```